# "If" Construct in Unix Scripting

Tags: shell, unix

I have just started writing shell scripts.  In `if` constructs, is the `if` considered to be a command or a keyword?

If it is a command, its path should be listed when searched through the `which` command.  In reality, `which` does not find anything.

If `if` is not a command then ideally it does not need to be separated by a semicolon when `then` is written in the same line.

Can any of you please explain whether `if` is a command or a statement?

Comment: It can't be an external command, because it has to affect the behavior of commands and statements that come after it in the script, and also has to match up with the `fi` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

In [bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) `if` is a compound command (see "Shell Grammar" in the linked page.)

Comment: Yes! Please read the bash man page. It has a lot of information on scripting.

Comment: Also, be aware of bash features that are extensions beyond what the POSIX `sh` (Bourne Shell) supports and mark your scripts as `#!/bin/bash` scripts if they require such features.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_07

Answer (score 0):

`if` is not a command it is the shell's construct.

Semicolon `;` after condition is the shell syntax to terminate the condition and **is required only when `then` keyword is on the same line**. `;` is not mandatory when `then` keyword appears on the next line.

So this will also work without semicolon and print date:

```
if ((RANDOM>0))
then
    date
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`if` is a keyword.  The semi-colon terminates the command that is between `if` and `then`.